# iOS - How can I get the label of a table row from commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have a UITableView which is populated by the array keys from an NSMutableDictionary.

To be able to delete these arrays I need to be able to get the key in some way. My thoughts were the easiest was to get it from the label of the row.

I'm using this code to load the dictionary:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)plistPath];
```

and this to remove the array from the dictionary:

```
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:];
```

But obviously I'm missing they key as I don't know how to grab it programatically. Any tips?

Cheers,

Chris

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>(null)</key>
    <array>
        <string>Username</string>
        <string>Password</string>
        <string>http://www.google.com</string>
        <string>/whatever</string>
    </array>
    <key>Hello</key>
    <array>
        <string>admin</string>
        <string></string>
        <string>https://www.whatever.com</string>
        <string>/things</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewerName"];

        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
        label.text = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

Delete Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)plistPath];
    NSString *key = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: `[[dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: Show a few lines of your plist. (In Xcode, right-click and "Open As" -> "Source Code"). Please put this into your **question** not as a comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think that does not guarantee the correct order....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never get data from the table cell. You already have data structures that you used to populate the table cell, get your data from those same data structures.

You must have some sort of an array in place so you can get the proper data for each cell. Use the same array to get the data for the row being deleted.

If you show some code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, a more concrete answer could be given. But it's basically the same code to get the data based on the `indexPath`.

The code you posted so far only shows a dictionary. A dictionary isn't a good basis for a row based structure like a table.

**Update**: based on the code from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, all you need is:

```
NSString *key = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Update 2**: Why are you loading the file again in the `commitEditingStyle` method? You need to modify the existing data structure you already have loaded for the table. As it stands now, you have data structures used by the table. Then in `commitEditingStyle`, you load up the data again, delete an entry from this temporary data, then you tell the table to  reload. The reload will use the original data structures, not this temporary data.

Also, don't call both `reloadData` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Just call one or the other.

And this line:

```
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key]];
```

should be:

```
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
```

Do not use `stringWithFormat` unless you actually have a string that you are formatting.

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewerName"];
        
        
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
        label.text = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}`

Comment: Ok, my `viewerKeys` is an ivar `NSArray` that holds all the keys in the plist. When I change that to `NSMutableArray` at `viewerKeys = [dictionary allKeys]` I get the error `incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *___strong' from 'NSArray *`... I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong here...

Comment: Ok, i've changed viewerKeys successfully by changing it to `[viewerKeys addObjectsFromArray:[dictionary allKeys]];` but now my table isn't being populated...